# Homework Assignment: Assistance with placing a running for loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send the suggested text file to the xampp server but I would like to know how to strip out and only show results 1- 10 in a loop and when the button2 is pressed to show results 11-20. Then when you press the button a third time it will show results 21-30. Once I have that finished I would like to know how to reverse this order when I press a backwards button.

both buttons need to show up after I request the text file within the box1

```
</style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var i;
    var highlight;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#button1").click(function() {
                $.get("topHits1990.txt", function(data, status) {
                    console.log("The data is below");
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log("The status is below");
                    console.log(status);
                        $("#box1").html(data);
                        $("#button2").show();
                        $("#button3").show();

});

            $("#button2").click(function() {
                    $.get("topHits1990.txt", function(data, status) {
                            for (i=0 i > 9; i++) 
                                $("#box1").html(data);
                            }

                        } else if (i>10 i++) {

                });


        });




    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Favorite Songs</h1>
    <button type="button" id="button1">Show Songs</button>
    <div id="box1"></div>

</body>
```

I would like to get to increment everytime you press a button and decrement when you press the backwards button and I would like to hide the forward and backward buttons within the running function. I am sorta a beginner at jQuery mixed with Javascript so any creative criticism is welcome.

It only shows the whole text file and does not limit how much data you are able to see which I am trying to limit it to 10 entries at a time everytime you press either of the buttons.

The function does not work as you have to use a xampp server with my requested files as it is an ajax, jquery and javascript task.

Comment: Hi Cedric - I'd be surprised if you get a response here, this looks blatantly like a homework assignment

Comment: That's not the kind of question you should ask on here, for someone to design code for you. Do the work, try things and come back with specific questions. If you're good enough to do what you've done, you're good enough to get it closer

Comment: To follow up on @pentaphobe 's comment - in fact, if you stated at the top it was a homework question, you'd be *more* likely to get a response!

Comment: I also can't see what the relationship between *showing* values and *sending* the file is - they seem to be separate activities.  You either read the whole file and show parts of it or you read parts of the file and show all that you've read - but what has showing got to do with the sending? What are you sending? to where?

Comment: @pentaphobe It is a homework assignment I am just stuck on trying to figure out how to right a loop that only sends out a certain amount of entries.. I have tried to ask everyone I know but have been forced to try the internet.  sorry it is a homework assignment I have been trying for a atleast a week on trying to figure this out..  Thanks for the tip I made changes that accordingly will better my search

Comment: @freedomn-m I am trying to send the text file to box 1 which works fine without all the added the lines of code after this line $("#box1").html(data); but then I am trying to grab only 10 entries instead of the whole 30 entries that show up I basically want to hide 20 entries and show 10 at a time.But then I confused on how to start something like this.. Im not book smart when it comes to coding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to send the text file to box 1,  but only 10 entries instead of the whole 30

First you need to know how to only get x entries.  You do this by splitting the text file into records - You need to determine what separates each record, ie the separator.

Is topHits1990.txt a text file that has one row per line?  Or is it comma separated?  Possibly, separated by `;`.   You use this separator to split thre block of data into records.

Assuming it's one row per line, the separator would be newline or `\n`.

You then convert/break-up the single text file into "records", in this case:

```
var records=data.split("\n");
```

or

```
var records=data.split(",");
```

This gives you an array which you can then manipulate as required.

You could loop through the array, for simplicity, eg:

```
var records=data.split(",");
var result = "";
for (var i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    result = result + records[i] + "\n";
}
$("#box1").text(result);
```

or you could use something a bit fancier, such as [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) combined with join, eg:

```
var records=data.split("\n");  // use whatever separator is required here
$("#box1").text(records.slice(0, 9).join("\n"));
```

To show the 'next' set of records, you just need to change the starting position.

Putting it all together:

```js
// This would be the result of your $.get
var data = "row1,row2,row3,row4,row5,row6,row7,row8,row9,row10";

// number of rows to show - 3 for demo, change to 10
var rowstoshow = 3; 

// current position, clicking the button moves to the *next* position
// so need to indicate we haven't started yet
var position = -1;

$("#btn").click(function() {

    // split the data into rows
    var rows = data.split(",");

    // Move to next position, check if first, reset if too far
    position = position < 0 ? 0 : position + rowstoshow;
    if (position > rows.length) position = 0
   
    // slice the array to get the correct records then join them using \n for output
    var newtxt = rows.slice(position, position+rowstoshow).join("\n")
    $("#box1").text(newtxt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows=10 cols=60 id='box1'></textarea>
<button id='btn'>click me</button>
```

To reverse the action, add another button and in its click event subtract the number of rows to show from position, checking for `< 0` and resetting to `rows.length - rowstoshow` (not just rows.length as it shows from that position).

---

Note: As this is a homework assignment and you're relatively new to coding, the solution above uses something called 'global variables' in "real" code this is not best practice and you would want to avoid these as they pollute the global namespace, so you would use scope and/or namespaces to store these, or even store them directly in the html using `data-` attributes.

Comment: freedomn-m thank you so much for the help this exactly what I wanted to know how to do so now I will take what you gave me and build off of its always the first step that trips me up on what to do. Also the text file is like this <h1>Top Hit Rap Songs From 1990s</h1>


<p><span class="p1">1</span><span class="p2">Ha</span><span class="p3">Juvenile</span></p>
<p><span class="p1">2</span><span class="p2">Don’t Sweat The Technique</span><span class="p3">Eric B & Rakim</span></p>
 its like this repeated 30 times with 30 different entries and uses the p1 , p2 and p3 classes and writes them

Comment: If it's in that format, then you can parse it as html when you load it, eg: `$.get("topHits1990.txt", function(data, status) { var html = $(data); ` then use jquery to extract what you want, eg `var txt = html.find(".p2"),map(function() { return $(this).text(); }).get().join("\n"); $("#box1").text(txt);`